# The argument type 'List<ImageModel>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageModel'

Tags: flutter

I created an application through the language of flutter to display the slide show. Through the displayed images, I try to enable the user to click on the image and move to the next page with the image ID taken.

I created the following code to do that, but I am faced the following problem:

```
The argument type 'List<ImageModel>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageModel'.
```

```
class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<Demo> {

bool lodaing=true;
List<ImageModel> imageModel  ;
  List data;
  Future GetAllCategory()async{
    var response=await http.get("https://****************.php"
        , headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}
    );
    var jsoBody = response.body;
    var jsoData =json.decode(jsoBody);
    setState(() {
      data= jsoData;
      lodaing=false;
    });
      print('show all data $jsoData');
  }
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    GetAllCategory();
  }

var getId;

void _gotoSingleImage(ImageModel imageModel, BuildContext context) {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SingleImage(imageModel)),
  );
}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(
      body:lodaing?   CircularProgressIndicator() :

      GestureDetector(

        child:

        Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 150.0,
          width: 300.0,

          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {

              _gotoSingleImage( imageModel, context);

            },

            child: Carousel(

      
              boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
              autoplay: true,
              dotSize: 4.0,
              dotSpacing: 15.0,
              dotColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
              indicatorBgPadding: 5.0,
              dotBgColor: Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.5),
              borderRadius: true,

      
              images:

              data  .map(
                    (list) {
              
                        return Image.network(list['image']

                        );
                        },

              )
                  .toList(),


            ),



          ),

        ),
      ),
      )




    );
  }
}

class SingleImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final ImageModel imageModel;
  SingleImage(this.imageModel);

  @override
  _SingleImageState createState() => _SingleImageState();
}

class _SingleImageState extends State<SingleImage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    print(widget.imageModel);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('ImageScreen'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          //  print(widget.getId.toString());
        ));
  }
}


class ImageModel {
  int id;
  String src;

  ImageModel({
    this.id,
    this.src,
  });

  factory ImageModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ImageModel(
    id: json["id"],
    src: json["src"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "src": src,
  };
}

class ImageUrl {
  ImageUrl({
    this.id,
    this.src,
    this.name,
    this.alt,
  });

  int id;
  String src;
  String name;
  String alt;

  factory ImageUrl.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ImageUrl(
    id: json["id"],
    src: json["src"],
    name: json["name"],
    alt: json["alt"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "src": src,
    "name": name,
    "alt": alt,
  };
}
```

I get the error in:

```
onTap: () {

              _gotoSingleImage( imageModel, context);

            },
```

A picture that clarifies the problem more:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmEBt.png)

Could someone help me to solve that.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`_gotoSingleImage` takes an instance of `ImageModel` and a context. However, you call it using the variable `imageModel` which you declared as a `List<ImageModel>`. That doesn’t work. So you got to change the type of `imageModel` or modify the method `_gotoSingleImage` accordingly.

Side note: That’s not specific to Flutter or Dart (which is the language you’re writing in), so I recommend making yourself familiar with how functions and methods work in general. You’re gonna need this basic knowledge, no matter which language you’re using.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it all wrong ! first of all you are putting a `List` of `imageModel` where should be just one , you can try and do something like this :

**Note:** i have tried it with `carousel_Slider` package cuz that's the one i have

```
 child: CarouselSlider(
          items: data.map((i) {
            return Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        child: Image.network(i, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                        onTap: () {
                         _gotoSingleImage( i, context);

                            ),
                          );
                        }));
              },
            );
          }).toList(),
        ));
```

Comment: Hello brother / I modified the code according to your instructions and I got the following error: The getter 'initialPage' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: initialPage